# Вывод через print в python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как подключить antigate в python 3.4 в парсер google?

Подключаю библиотеку, а при выводе `print AntiGate ('API-KEY', 'captcha.jpg')` - выдает `invalid syntax`

Comment: В питоне3 используется не оператор `print`, а функция `print(...)`: `print(AntiGate('API-KEY', 'captcha.jpg'))`

Comment: да, получилось, спасибо

Comment: Я тогда, продублирую комментарий в ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел в списке вопросов без ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) используется не оператор `print`, а функция `print(...)`:

```
print(AntiGate('API-KEY', 'captcha.jpg'))
```